# Splitting Pandas Row Data into Multiple Rows without Adding Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some American Football data in a DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Green Bay Packers' : ['30-18-0', '5-37', '10-71' ],
                    'Chicago Bears' : ['45-26-1', '5-20', '10-107']}, 
                 index=['Att - Comp - Int', 'Sacked - Yds Lost', 'Penalties - Yards'])
```

```
                    Green Bay Packers   Chicago Bears
Att - Comp - Int    30-18-0               45-26-1
Sacked - Yds Lost   5-37                    5-20
Penalties - Yards   10-71                  10-107
```

You can see above that each row contains multiple data points that need to be split off.
What I'd like to do is find some way to split the rows up so that each data point is it's own row. The final output would like like:

```
        Green Bay Packers   Chicago Bears
Att           30                45
Comp          18                26
Int            0                 1
Sacked         5                 5
Yds Lost      37                20
Penalties     10                10
Yards         71               107
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently? I tried some Regex but it just turned into a mess. Sorry if my formatting isn't perfect...2nd question ever posted here.

Comment: Convert the values into a string and then recreate the data with corresponding values. That is what I would do

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: x.str.split("-"))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {c: df[c].explode().str.strip() for c in df.columns},
).set_index("index")
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Green Bay Packers Chicago Bears
Att                      30            45
Comp                     18            26
Int                       0             1
Sacked                    5             5
Yds Lost                 37            20
Penalties                10            10
Yards                    71           107
```

Answer (score 0):

First reset the index, then stack all the columns and split them on `-`, You can also additionally apply to remove any left over whitespace characters after after using split, then unstack again, then apply `pd.Series.explode` finally reset the index, and drop any left-over  unrequired column.

```py
out =  (df.reset_index()
        .stack().str.split('-').apply(lambda x:[i.strip() for i in x])
        .unstack()
        .apply(pd.Series.explode)
        .reset_index()
        .drop(columns='level_0'))

        index Green Bay Packers Chicago Bears
0        Att                 30            45
1       Comp                 18            26
2         Int                 0             1
3     Sacked                  5             5
4    Yds Lost                37            20
5  Penalties                 10            10
6       Yards                71           107
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have same number of splits for every row, with [pandas >= 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode), you can explode multiple columns at the same time:

```
df = df.reset_index().apply(lambda s: s.str.split(' *- *'))
df.explode(df.columns.tolist()).set_index('index')

          Green Bay Packers Chicago Bears
index
Att                      30            45
Comp                     18            26
Int                       0             1
Sacked                    5             5
Yds Lost                 37            20
Penalties                10            10
Yards                    71           107
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on each column (including index) and for each column:

- use [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split data points and
- use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to create rows for each split data point element

```
df_out = (df.reset_index()
            .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(r'\s*-\s*').explode())
            .set_index('index').rename_axis(index=None)
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

          Green Bay Packers Chicago Bears
Att                      30            45
Comp                     18            26
Int                       0             1
Sacked                    5             5
Yds Lost                 37            20
Penalties                10            10
Yards                    71           107
```